# Select value of a column that corresponds to highest value of another column with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,2], 'perc':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], 'category':['a','b','b','a']})
```

I would like to create an extra column which will be the `category` that corresponds to the **highest** `perc` by `id`.

The resulting dataframe looks like:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,2], 'perc':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], 'category':['a','b','b','a'], 'category_max':['b','b','a','a']})
```

Any ideas how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with convert `category` to index, so for maximal caegory by `perc` per group use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), last for assign back is necessary convert ouput to numpy array for prevent alignment (because is different index after `transform` like in original `df`):

```
foo['category_max'] = (foo.set_index('category')
                          .groupby('id')['perc']
                          .transform('idxmax')
                          .to_numpy())
print (foo)
   id  perc category category_max
0   1   0.1        a            b
1   1   0.2        b            b
2   2   0.3        b            a
3   2   0.4        a            a
```

Or is possible mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by aggregate values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
foo['category_max'] = foo['id'].map(foo.set_index('category')
                                       .groupby('id')['perc']
                                       .idxmax())
print (foo)
   id  perc category category_max
0   1   0.1        a            b
1   1   0.2        b            b
2   2   0.3        b            a
3   2   0.4        a            a
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`GroupBy.transform('idxmax')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
foo['category_max'] = (foo
                       .set_index('category')
                       .groupby('id')['perc']
                       .transform('idxmax').values
                      )
```

output:

```
   id  perc category category_max
0   1   0.1        a            b
1   1   0.2        b            b
2   2   0.3        b            a
3   2   0.4        a            a
```